# One of character for button Apply Now is hidden due to h5

Tags: html, css

Last character for button Apply Now is hidden. How to make it show?

The problem occur because I included them together with title's h5.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nNw62/13/)

Comment: It's visible for me - FF 15.0.1 on Ubuntu

Comment: I am only having this issue in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase the width to 110px:

```
input.buttonApply {
    background: url(button.png) 0 30 no-repeat;
    width: 110px; height: 30px;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The solution is ok for ie, chrome and firefox (i tested it)